# How to override a jQuery style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jquery to move items between selectable lists. Here is my jquery code

```
   listItems.fadeOut(function() {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("ui-selected")
      .clone()
      .appendTo("#target-list")
       .html( $(this).html() + '</a><a href="https://www.google.ie/" target="_blank"> Edit </a>' )
      .fadeIn()
      .data("index", $("#source-list li").index($(this)))
      .highlight();
  });
```

This produces the following html

```
   <li id="1" class="ui-selectee ui-selected" style="display: list-item;">
   Everton
   <a class="ui-selectee" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.ie/">
    Search
   </a>
   </li>
```

This will not allow the link window to open as jquery is applying the "ui-selectee" class to the ahref. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `selectable` has a `filter` option, you can try excluding your `a` element from the selectee list, such as by `filter: ":not(a)"`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I added this.

```
   $("#target-list").selectable({
    cancel: 'a'
    });
```